# Отступы между элементами таблицы

Tags: c#, wpf

В общем, вот такой интерфейс:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просто таблица из 3-ех столбцов.

Я пытался найти, как задать расстояние между строками и столбцами таблицы, но не нашел.

Можно ли это как-то сделать через стили, чтобы руками у каждого элемента не прописывать?

Я нашел вот такое решение, но что-то оно у меня не работает...

```
    <Style TargetType="Border" >
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,10,10,10" />
    </Style>
```

Пример разметки, но я тут уже руками успел прописать везде Margin...

```
<Window x:Class="DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows.SourceConfigurationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DictionaryCreator.UI.Windows"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Конфигурация источника" Height="420" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="500" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image" >
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="30" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Тип базы данных</Label>
        <ComboBox Margin="5"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DbKinds}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDbKind}"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Сервер (MSSQL) или путь к файлу (MS ACCESS)</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" Text="{Binding Path=FilePathOrServerName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название базы данных</Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=DbNameEnable}" Text="{Binding Path=DbName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Название таблицы</Label>
        <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TableDescriptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedTableDescription}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Schema}" />
                            <Run Text="." />
                            <Run Text="{Binding TableName}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </Grid>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Command="{Binding Path=RefreshTablesCommand}" >
            <Image Width="30" Height="20" Source="../Icons/Refresh.png"/>
            <Button.ToolTip>
                Обновить
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>

        <Label Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Margin="5">Ключ таблицы (целое число)</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedKeyColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="5" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Поле нормализуемого значения</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedValueColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>
        <Label Grid.Row="6" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">Идентификатор привязки к справочнику</Label>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="6" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ColumnDescriptions}" DisplayMemberPath="ColumnName" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDictKeyColumnDescription}"></ComboBox>

        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="7"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 30 0 0">
            <Button Margin="0 0 25 0" 
                    Command="{Binding Path=SaveCommand}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Margin="5 0 0 0" Source="../Icons/Save.png"/>
                        <Label>Сохранить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
            <Button  Margin="0 0 25 0" 
                    Command="{Binding Path=CancelCommand}">
                <Button.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Margin="5 0 0 0"  Source="../Icons/Cancel.png"/>
                        <Label>Отменить</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>

        </WrapPanel>
      
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />` или `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,5,5,5" />`, что в принципе одно и то же.

Comment: @aepot так тоже пробовал, но не работает почему-то =((

Comment: У меня работает. Но без разметки не понять. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1256729/373567 вот я предлагал вам разметку, вы правда никак не отреагировали, и я удалил ответ, плюс на меня напал там EvgeniyZ и начал гнобить за то что я показываю практики а не прямо отвечаю на вопрос.

Comment: @aepot разметку я добавил

Comment: Не могу найти в разметке `<Border>`, к которому вы пытаетесь применить стиль.

Comment: @aepot Т.е каждый элемент я должен в Border бернуть? Эх, а я думал, что все автоматом как-то сделается)

Comment: Ну в border не обязательно оборачивать (так даже длиннее получится), можно просто прописать стиль для всех элементов с Margin. С помощью наследования стилей это можно будет чуть-чуть сократить. По сути вам нужны стили для Label, ComboBox, TextBox...

Comment: Ещё один вариант, если у вас много где такие гриды нужны — написать свою панель, которая будет делать отступы между ячейками самостоятельно